# How can I auto detect current form's id in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-forms, validation

I want to create a custom email validator to check if email exists or no to do that I must know the form's id so that to get its data I can do that using this code

```
ID ID = new ID("{form id}");
var data = this.FormDataProvider.GetEntries(ID.Guid, null, null);
```

so its hard coded which I don't want as it will work for only one form and I want it to be general
How can I auto detect the ID of the form through code?

Comment: I feel you can follow this link "https://sitecorescientist.com/2018/11/02/sitecore-9-forms-part-1-basic-form-with-email-exist-validation/", a custom validator that you can create once and reuse.

Comment: @DebabrataBiswas great it worked thanks